# PDF intent in android

Tags: java, android

while developing an android app , I am getting error "sorry we were unable to find the document at the original source" while using the following code : please advise

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading( WebView view, String url ) {
            if (url.contains(".pdf")){
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "chand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
                  view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                //String googleDocs = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="; 
                //view.loadUrl(googleDocs + url);
            //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "chand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //String pdfurl = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url;
                //Log.i(TAG, "Opening PDF: " + url);
                //view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
                //view.loadUrl(pdfurl);


            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: where is the pdf located?

Comment: it's in an external link

Answer (score 0):

To use that intent you need to download the PDF to the device onto the sdcard then give the uri to the pdf on the sd card in the intent.

Comment: Thank you...will implement that...is this true for ms word, ms ppt, ms excel also?

Comment: probably but I dont know, I never used them